# How to use a 1 byte memory as an array index?

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, nasm

I have a byte array in which `[ebp - 4]` (4 bytes) stores the address of its first element. I also have another variable `[ebp - 5]` (1 byte) that stores the current index to this array.

Now I want to access an element of this array using the combination `base+index` but this format requires for both registers to be 32-bit (e.g. `eax` and not `al`), so what I did is zero up the `eax` register and then `mov` the 1 byte `[ebp - 5]` into `al` and then using the entire `eax` register as an index:

```
mov eax, 0
mov al, [ebp - 5]
```

Is this is how this sort of thing is usually done? Is there's another way to directly `mov` a 1 byte memory into a register?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While that works, there is a `movzx` instruction that moves with zero extension:

`movzx eax, byte [ebp - 5]`.

There is also `movsx` for sign extending but that's not useful for array indexing.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `movzx eax, BYTE [ebp - 5]`?

Comment: For Microsoft / Intel assember, it's movzx eax,byte ptr [ebp-5] .

Comment: As an alternative, you could specify a 511 byte array or allocate it, then round up a pointer to the array to a 256 byte boundary (in c, this would be ptr256 = (ptr+255)&(~0x100); ) . Then just use the lower order byte of ptr256 as an index while leaving the upper 3 bytes alone.